# Search function duplicates data vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, datagridview

[image]

I have a select query to search the data from access but the problem is that the search function duplicates each line (show the same line 2 times in DGV). Can anyone guide me to the problem thanks in advance.

```
    Dim sql = "SELECT A.* FROM  ((tblMatrice AS B INNER JOIN tblRefMatrice AS C ON B.strMatrice = C.strMatrice) INNER JOIN tblRefMatDetails AS D ON C.intIDref = D.intIDRef) LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDopages AS A on A.strMatrice = B.strMatrice where "

    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, myConnection)

    If CKBrefech.Checked = True Then
         sql = sql & "strRefEch = @Refech  AND "
    End If

    sql = sql & "strMethode = @Methode AND "

    sql = sql & "strPurif = @Purif AND "


    If CKBmatrice.Checked Then
         sql = sql & "A.strMatrice = @Matrice AND "
    End If

    sql = sql & "strMolecule = @Molecule AND "

    If CKBechprep.Checked Then
        sql = sql & "datDatePrepa >= @DatPrepa AND "
    End If
    If CKBechau.Checked Then
        sql = sql & "datDatePrepa <= @Datau AND "
    End If
    If CKBtrigprepa.Checked = True Then
       sql = sql & "strTrigPrepa = @Trigprep AND "
    End If
    If CKBtriganaly.Checked = True Then
       sql = sql & "strTrigAnaly = @Triganaly AND "
    End If
    If CKBappar.Checked = True Then
       sql = sql & "strNomTech = @Tech AND "
    End If
    If CKBnumappar.Checked = True Then
       sql = sql & "[strEquip(Appareil)] = @Equip AND "
    End If
    If CKBteneurmini.Checked = True Then
       sql = sql & "dblDopage > @TenMini AND "
    End If
    If CKBteneurmax.Checked = True Then
        sql = sql & "dblDopage < @TenMaxi AND "
    End If

    If GroupBox1.Enabled Then
        Try
            If CKBnomref.Checked Then
               sql = sql & "D.strReferentiel = @NomRef AND "
            End If
            If CKBniv1.Checked Then
               sql = sql & "D.strNIveau1 = @Niv1 AND "
            End If
            If CKBniv2.Checked Then
               sql = sql & "D.strNiveau2 = @Niv2 AND "
            End If
            If CKBniv3.Checked Then
               sql = sql & "D.strNiveau3 = @Niv3 AND "
            End If
            If CKBniv4.Checked Then
               sql = sql & "D.strNiveau4 = @Niv4 AND "
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If

    ' Remove the last AND if any ....'
    If sql.EndsWith(" AND ") Then
        sql = sql.Substring(0, sql.Length - 4)
    End If
    ' Remove the WHERE if no textbox has been filled....'
    If sql.EndsWith(" WHERE ") Then
        sql = sql.Substring(0, sql.Length - 7)
    End If

    sql = sql & " ORDER BY datDatePrepa ASC "


    cmd.CommandText = sql
    cmd.Connection = myConnection
    Dim MyDataSet As New DataSet
    MyDataSet.Clear()
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, myConnection)
    da.SelectCommand = cmd


    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Methode", CBmethode.Text))         'adding Methode parameters to datatable
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Purif", CBpurif.Text))             'adding Purif parameters to datatable
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Matrice", CBmatrice.Text))         'adding Matrice parameters to datatable
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Molecule", CBmol.Text))            'adding Molecule parameters to datatable
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@DatPrepa", DTPechprep.Value))      'adding date parameters to datatable
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@datau", DTPechprep.Value))         'adding date parameters to datatable
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Trigprep", TBtrigprepa.Text))      'adding Trigprep parameters to datatable
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Triganaly", TBtrigAnaly.Text))     'adding Triganaly parameters to datatable
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Tech", CBappar.Text))              'adding Tech parameters to datatable
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Equip", CBnumappar.Text))          'adding Equip parameters to datatable
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@TenMini", TBteneurmini.Text))      'adding TenMini parameters to datatable
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@TenMaxi", TBteneurmax.Text))       'adding TenMaxi parameters to datatable
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@NomRef", CBnomref.Text))           'adding TenMaxi parameters to datatable
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Niv1", CBniv1.Text))               'adding Niv1 parameters to datatable
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Niv2", CBniv2.Text))               'adding Niv2 parameters to datatable
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Niv3", CBniv3.Text))               'adding Niv3 parameters to datatable
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Niv4", CBniv4.Text))               'adding Niv4 parameters to datatable

    da.Fill(MyDataSet, "Matrice")

    DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
    DataGridView1.DataSource = MyDataSet.Tables("Matrice")
    'to focus on first row of DGV after populating it 

    myConnection.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally the problem is the join between tables.

If the relationship is not specified in the right way, this can duplicate rows.

Look that you use the right keys for joining te tables.

In your case, for what i can see, the problem is the table of details, you will have a row for each detail in the table.

Comment: I'm sure that the problem is not the joining of tables because i made the same query without parameters and it worked very well. So the problem is somewhere in the parameters or dataset ... btw please clarify the last line of your comment @Daniele

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your query is returning unique rows. Try to add a distinct keyword.

Comment: No that doesn't suite me because i may have the same line twice in the database @Muhammad Irfan Azam

Comment: If you can share some sample data with duplicate rows that you want to keep and rows that you dont want to keep then it will be helpful to suggest a solution

Comment: Ok for me the problem is that it duplicate each row of the search result like if your result contains 50 lines it will show 100 lines so the problem is that the query shows each line duplicated @Muhammad Irfan Azam

Comment: It would be difficult to say anything if we dont see any data sample. Still i will suggest to use distinct.

Comment: I add an image and my table doesn't have primary key so data could be duplicated but **manually** . If i duplicate the results I should display them but till now if the table contains 100 lines it will show them as 200 lines in the search result @Muhammad Irfan Azam

Comment: I have looked at your query carefully. You are displayed only records from table tblDopages. This table has a left outer join with strMatrice. This is expected behavior for the joins specified.

If you can add some column from table strMatrice then you will have better view of why data is being duplicated or may be duplication is removed.

If you only want to display output columns from tblDoPages then you can safely use distinct keyword.

Comment: Man for God's sake stop telling me to use Distinct :p that doesn't solve the problem for me. BTW my tblMatrice contains 1 column and it's the primary  key. @Muhammad Irfan Azam

Comment: Can u send me table structure with sample records so that i can reproduce it on my side. Otherwise all efforts will be in vain.

Comment: how can I send you the them ?

Comment: In form of scripts in a zip file or update ur question with scripts. Or i dont know if we can share email here.

Comment: Ok Give me your mail please

Answer (score -1):

Well the problem is so normal because i have duplicated data in a table so the the reaction of Inner Join is normal to duplicate data. I deleted the duplicated data and every thing works well now.